# What is meaning and significance of locally decrementing SP (Stack Pointer)?

Tags: cpu, alu, stack-pointer

[image]

What is meaning of line "SP (Stack Pointer) can be decremented locally"

*I am not asking the answer of the whole question in the image.

Comment: It means that there's something inside the **SP** box that provides the necessary stripped-down decrementor logic for that purpose. In short, the **SP** box is *not* just a register. It's got some extra machinery that they are not showing you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, locally means using the circuitry you have or shown there, not using circuitry elsewhere.

It means the Stack Pointer SP can be decremented within that SP block. That's where the 'subtract 1' circuitry is.

It's emphasising that the CPU's ALU isn't needed to carry out the decrement.